# Fail to install pip in Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I wanted to install pip, the error just came out:

```
C:\Users\xd>python get-pip.py install
Collecting install
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 589, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 797, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\xd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf2uneu6f\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    if host.startswith('['):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

What can I do?

Comment: fwiw, the expected invocation is `python get-pip.py` not `python get-pip.py install` (which attempts to install a package named `install`)

Answer (score 0):

For recent Python versions (3.4+), you don't need to use the get-pip.py script anymore. Just run `python -m ensurepip`, and the ensurepip module will do everything the get-pip.py script used to do.

Comment: I've succeeded to install pip, but the error still existed. When I was using "pip3 install pandas", the terminal showed me the same error as I copied in my question.