# pip exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, windows, pip

When I use pip to install some packages, I always get the same exception:

```sh
PS C:\Users\84682\Desktop> pip install django -v
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Collecting django
  1 location(s) to search for versions of django:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 589, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 797, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    if host.startswith('['):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 589, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 797, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "d:\python\python3.5\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    if host.startswith('['):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I found the similar question is [python can not be used in win10？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014188/python-can-not-be-used-in-win10), [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783496/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-startswith) and [Fail to install pip in Python3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963402/fail-to-install-pip-in-python3-6). But they don't have answer.

---

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. I have no idea. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pip?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall python ?

Comment: @Sam Chats Yes, I have reinstall pip and python, but it still get this exception.

Comment: @SitiSchu I have tried python 3.6 and 3.5, but it didn't work.

Comment: What happens when you run `pip install --upgrade pip`  ?

Comment: @SitiSchu I get the same exception.

Comment: @SitiSchu I also have tried `download` and `search` command, but I got the same answer.

Comment: Reinstalling both python & pip did not help ? You seriously broke something then.

Comment: @SitiSchu If no solution, I will try to reinstall the system.

Comment: How are you installing pip?

Comment: @SamChats It's in python 3.6. I don't need to install it.

Comment: I think you should try installing it separately via its `setup.py` file.

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260169/python-locationvalueerror-no-host-specified

Comment: It's a request problem and I am working on a patch. See https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error message trying to run `pip` from a docker compose. The underlying problem which caused the error was that I had defined my proxy setting with one slash too few: `http:/myproxy...` .

Then after correcting that bug everything worked.

I hope this helps somebody who has the same problem.