# "AttributeError: 'NoneType'" shows up everytime I use pip

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

I can install wheels but can't use "pip install 'module'", its like I just can't install those modules from the Internet.

**Error**

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

In spite of tensorflow, usual modules like "requests" or "numpy" can't be installed by pip.

```
C:\Users\Think>pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in 
    run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in 
    prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in 
    _prepare_file
require_hashes
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in 
    populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in 
    find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in 
    find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 
     488, in get
     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
     return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 
     475, in request
     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 
     596, in send
     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", 
     line 47, in send
     resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
     File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", 
     line 423, in send
     timeout=timeout
 File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-
     packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 
     589, in urlopen
     self._prepare_proxy(conn)
 File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-
     packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 
     797, in _prepare_proxy
     conn.connect()
 File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-
     packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 
     254, in connect
     conn = self._new_conn()
 File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 
      142, in _new_conn
     (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
 File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-
      packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", 
      line 66, in create_connection
 if host.startswith('['):
       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I'd appreciate if you could see the image:

[image]

Comment: add error stack as formated text

Comment: that image is awful, please provide a better one

Comment: sorry about that, I've updated it.

Comment: This is a proxy setting issue. Please check $HTTP_PROXY and $HTTPS_PROXY environment variable.

Comment: @danger89 Yes, I think you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the steps required for Anaconda installation of tensorflow through pip. It seems to be more elaborate that just `pip install tensorflow`:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation

Comment: no, not only tensorflow, I just can't pip anything on the internet, and the errors are the same.

Comment: then your pip is broken, try --upgrade of pip, reainstaling pip and python ect.

Comment: then most likely you facing the problem described here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3440#issuecomment-177458060

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern, there is this duplicate post, where the OP commented a solution to this problem was found:
[Resolved duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053826/pip-exception-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-startswith)

It would seem, your python path "D:\Anaconda3" might have something to do with errors using pip install. Try to install python on "C:\".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `pip`. It turned out to be an incorrectly formatted url for my proxy where I incorrectly used only one forward slash:

`http:/myproxy...`

After correcting the above to a working url, everything works.