# Cannot install using pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I'm trying to install matplotlib for python 3.6.3 using, but I keep getting this exception all the time. I have tried using the whl files too, to do it manually, but same result. I'm using this link to get the whl:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools

Also tried Anaconda, and python 2.7,3.4 and 3.5, and still can't fix the issue.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 589, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 797, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    if host.startswith('['):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: Is this error from just doing `pip install matplotlib` from the command line? Is it only matplotlib that this error happens?

Comment: Yeah that for that command. And no it happens for alot of other libraries I tried to install, so I downloaded the .whl's instead and some of them installed some of them didnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

You might have to use the full path to pip, if it's not in the PATH variable, like so:

```
C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip install --upgrade pip
```

Edit:
After searching and finding some duplicates on the web (with no solutions), it seems to me it might have something to do with the path of your python installation.
Such as: [duplicate 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053826/pip-exception-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-startswith), and [duplicate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158185/attributeerror-nonetype-shows-up-everytime-i-use-pip).

Is there a reason its not installed on the default C:\Python36-32 folder?
You might want to download and install the windows msi installer for python in the recommended way, and see where that gets you.

***Solution:***

After OP's comment, it seems that moving Python to C:\ path (preferably with a clean install with windows .msi from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) should fix this issue.

Comment: I get the same error as above when trying to upgrade, and I've already got pip in the PATH

Comment: Success!!!!!!! Reinstalled it to that folder and it worked, thank you very much been at it since yesterday haha